# How to operate reduceByKey on a reduceByKey result

Tags: pyspark, rdd

Im  trying to execute a `reduceByKey` on a `reduceByKey` result.
The goal is to see if we have long-tail effect in each year - long tail here means than i want to see for each year (separately) if 65% or more from this year sales are from 20% or less products.

This is my data set:
data set - year and asin(its an ID)

[image: 1]

I want to first - reduce by year, and then to every year (seperately) to reduce by asin.
therefore i will get for every year, how many times each product occurred.

i tried to do this:

```py
data_rdd.map(lambda x: (x.Year,(x.asin,1))).groupByKey().mapValues(list).sortBy(lambda x: x[0]).map(lambda x: x[1])
```

but I don't understand how I do a `reducebykey` to each line

thanks

Comment: Did you tried to map using as key (year, asin), then doing a reduceByKey? With that, you can get for year pair year-asin how many products are done.

data_rdd.map(lambda x: ((x.Year, x.asin), 1)).reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `SparkSQL` API in that case because windows are going to be very helpful. For each year, let's compute the percentage of products needed to achieve at least 65% of the sales:

```py
# let's create some sample data. I assume we have one line per sale
df = spark.createDataFrame([('2020', 'prod1'), ('2020', 'prod1'), ('2020', 'prod1'),
    ('2020', 'prod1'), ('2020', 'prod1'), ('2020', 'prod3'), ('2020', 'prod1'),
    ('2020', 'prod2'),  ('2020', 'prod2'),  ('2020', 'prod3'),  ('2020', 'prod4'),
    ('2020', 'prod5')], ['year', 'asin'])

# let's start by counting the number of sales per product, per year
df.groupBy("year", "asin").count().show()
```

```
+----+-----+-----+
|year| asin|count|
+----+-----+-----+
|2020|prod1|    6|
|2020|prod3|    2|
|2020|prod2|    2|
|2020|prod4|    1|
|2020|prod5|    1|
+----+-----+-----+
```

Now, let's use windows to compute things we will need to answer your question:

- total number of product per year: `product_count`
- total number of sales per year: `total_sales`
- the cumulative number of sales, starting from the product that was sold the most: `cum_sales`
- a product index, starting from the product that was sold the most: `product_index From there,` product_per`is the percentage of product,`sales_per`the percentage of sales so that we can see if at least 65% of the sales were made by less than 20% of the products. We can finally compute`dist`, the distance of the sales percentage to 65%. We will use that column to keep the first row that allows to reach more than 65% of sales.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

ordered_window = Window.partitionBy("year").orderBy(f.col("count").desc(), "asin")
window = Window.partitionBy("year")

rich_df = df.groupBy("year", "asin").count()\
    .withColumn("product_count", f.count(f.col("*")).over(window))\
    .withColumn("total_sales", f.sum("count").over(window))\
    .withColumn("cum_sales", f.sum("count").over(ordered_window))\
    .withColumn("product_index", f.rank().over(ordered_window))\
    .withColumn("product_per", f.col("product_index") / f.col("product_count"))\
    .withColumn("sales_per", f.col("cum_sales") / f.col("total_sales"))\
    .withColumn("dist", f.col("sales_per") - 0.65) 
rich_df.show()
```

```
+----+-----+-----+-------------+-----------+---------+-------------+-----------+------------------+--------------------+
|year| asin|count|product_count|total_sales|cum_sales|product_index|product_per|         sales_per|                dist|
+----+-----+-----+-------------+-----------+---------+-------------+-----------+------------------+--------------------+
|2020|prod1|    6|            5|         12|        6|            1|        0.2|               0.5|-0.15000000000000002|
|2020|prod2|    2|            5|         12|        8|            2|        0.4|0.6666666666666666|0.016666666666666607|
|2020|prod3|    2|            5|         12|       10|            3|        0.6|0.8333333333333334| 0.18333333333333335|
|2020|prod4|    1|            5|         12|       11|            4|        0.8|0.9166666666666666|  0.2666666666666666|
|2020|prod5|    1|            5|         12|       12|            5|        1.0|               1.0|                0.35|
+----+-----+-----+-------------+-----------+---------+-------------+-----------+------------------+--------------------+
```

So in this case, we need 40% of the products (2 out of 5) to reach at least 65% of the sales. Let's only keep that line:

```py
dist_win = Window.partitionBy("year").orderBy("dist")
rich_df.where(f.col("dist") >= 0)\
    .withColumn("dist_rank", f.rank().over(dist_win))\
    .where(f.col("dist_rank") == 1)\
    .select("year", "product_per", "sales_per", (f.col("product_per") < 0.2).alias("hasLongTail"))\
    .show()
```

```
+----+-----------+------------------+-----------+
|year|product_per|         sales_per|hasLongTail|
+----+-----------+------------------+-----------+
|2020|        0.4|0.6666666666666666|      false|
+----+-----------+------------------+-----------+
```

And that's going to work for more than one year ;-)

Comment: hey, thanks for your help!. The problem is I have to do this on pyspark and not us SQL :(

Comment: Well, this is pyspark. Do you mean you need to use RDDs? Is this an assignment?

Comment: Yes. i can only use rdd for this one, and I've try for days

Comment: Have you found what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use RDDs and that you don't have millions of distinct products, you can combine a `reduceByKey` to count sales per product per year, and a `groupByKey` to build a list of sales count per year. Then you can just use python code to compute what you want:

```py
# this function basically computes the cumulated sum of sales counts
# then, we find the number of products needed to achieve more than 65% of the sales
def percentageOfProducts(product_sales, sales_per=0.65):
    number_of_products = len(product_sales)
    number_of_sales = sum(product_sales)
    cumulated_sales = accumulate(sorted(product_sales, reverse=True))
    index = next(s[0] for s in enumerate(cumulated_sales) if s[1] / number_of_sales >= sales_per)
    return (index + 1) / number_of_products
 
result = data_rdd\
    .map(lambda x: ((x.year, x.asin),1))\
    .reduceByKey(lambda a, b : a+b)\
    .map(lambda x: (x[0][0], x[1]))\
    .groupByKey()\
    .mapValues(percentageOfProducts)
```